# Angular - show empty row by default in drop down list and disable button

Tags: html, angular

I need to do 2 things:

1) There's a dropdown list on my page that shows list of names. Currently, it shows name of a person on the top of the list by default (line 5). I would like to change it so that by default it does not show a name, forcing the user to select a name available in dropdown list.

2) Whilst there's no name is selected from dropdown, the send button should be disabled. It should be enabled only if user selects a name from dropdown.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" *ngIf="dealer.contacts && dealer.contacts.length" >
        <label>Contact person</label><br>
        <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="survey.answer.contact.email" (ngModelChange)="onContactChange($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let contact of dealer.contacts" [ngValue]="contact.email"> {{contact.title}} {{contact.firstname}} {{contact.lastname}}, {{contact.role}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" *ngIf="!dealer.contacts || !dealer.contacts.length" >
        <label>Contact person</label><br>
        <span class="label-error">No contacts present, please set up contacts in the Dossier!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" *ngIf="!survey.answer.emailStatus">
        <label>Date</label><br>
        <acc-datepickermanual id="startDate" [editable]="editable" (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)" [currentDate]="survey.answer.event.start"
                            [parentEndDate]="program.endDate" [parentStartDate]="program.startDate"></acc-datepickermanual>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [class.survey-button-sent]="sendingStatus == 'Sent'" (click)="sendNotifications($event)"
            [disabled]="sendingStatus !== 'Send'">
        {{sendingStatus}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you push an element at the front of  `dealer.contacts` array, which will represent nothing but empty value. Give it a specific value to be distinguished from  other. And  on `(ngModelChange)="onContactChange($event)"` check if that your first element then make button disabled, otherwise button is enabled.
If that's your problem or you have tried this thing ? or don't want to go through this approach.

Comment: Add some default option `--Select--`, and make it as selected by default.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar - sounds reasonable. How can I implement it within the code block above?

Comment: @HadidAli i have tried, and posted it as an answer, see if its helpful. If its not helpful, please comment then i will delete that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use html5's form validation stating that the element is `required` and setting `empty` option as default value therefore forcing the form to a invalid state.

For disabling the button on invalid state you could do like

`<button type="submit" [disabled] = "formName.invalid"></button>`

something like this:

```
 <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="survey.answer.contact.email" (ngModelChange)="onContactChange($event)" required>
      <option selected="" value="">-- Select Name -- </option> <!-- Select it as default but with empty value. -->
        <option *ngFor="let contact of dealer.contacts" [ngValue]="contact.email"> {{contact.title}} {{contact.firstname}} {{contact.lastname}}, {{contact.role}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You could add some description to add value to your answer.

Comment: Does not address the requirement. First element is not shown by default and button is not disabled when no contact is selected.

Comment: If you're taking advantage of [form validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) then you could disable the button using something like this
`<button type="submit" [disabled] = "survey.answer.contact.email || survey.answer.contact.email == 0"></button>`

Answer (score 0):

It is template driven form in which ngForm is used and submit button only be clickable when all inputs of form are valid other wise it will be disabled.

```
 <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post"  (ngSubmit)="contactForm($event)" #contactForm="ngForm"
     (ngSubmit)="sendNotifications($event)" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6" *ngIf="dealer.contacts && dealer.contacts.length" >
                <label>Contact person</label><br>
                <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="survey.answer.contact.email" name="email" id="email" #email="ngModel">
                    <option value="">Please select name</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let contact of dealer.contacts" [ngValue]="contact.email"> {{contact.title}} {{contact.firstname}} {{contact.lastname}}, {{contact.role}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                    [disabled]="contactForm.form.invalid">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please edit and add description to your answer, not in comments.

Comment: Does not address the requirement. First element is not shown by default and button is not disabled when no contact is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

I have added select option array's first element to be my dummy element. `{name: '---select---',email:'unwanted'}`, which i use to handle button's visibility.

1. By default, make button disable that is on first render of component.
2. Make button enable if dropdown changes and if its required change.
3. Make button disable if dropdown changes and if its not the required change.

See the demo version : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnfobg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Hope, it helps.